# Failed to open HDFS file after load data from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet, impala

I'm Using Java-Spark.

I'm loading `Parquet` data into Hive table as follow:

```
ds.write().mode("append").format("parquet").save(path);
```

Then I make

```
spark.catalog().refreshTable("mytable");//mytable is External table
```

And after I'm trying to see the data from `Impala` I got the following exception:

> Failed to open HDFS file
>
> No such file or directory. root cause: RemoteException: File does not exist

After I make on impala `refresh mytable` I can see the data.

How can I make the refresh command from `Spark`?

I'm try also

```
spark.sql("msck repair table mytable");
```

And still not working for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `spark.sql("refresh table mytable")` should work.

Comment: this is it, copy paste error on my answer

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala, After running your command actually the error gone but I still cant see the data (select count(*)  - return 0) only after I did "msck repair table mytable" on hive it's worked